# I do not know why my implementation of this scroll bar will not work

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am making an image deepfryer and need a scrollbar because if the image is bigger than 500x500, then the download button will not display as the image takes up the entire window.

I tried the following implementation and it did not work

function to display the given image using Tkinter

```py
def display_image(image):
    # convert the image to Tkinter format
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

    # create a canvas with a scrollbar
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
    canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

    scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
    scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

    canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))

    # display the image in the canvas
    canvas_image = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=image)
    canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

    # add a button to save the image
    save_button = tk.Button(canvas, text="Save", command=lambda: save_image(image))
    canvas.create_window(10, 10, anchor="nw", window=save_button)
```

Comment: We know that you probably don't know why the implementation of the scroll bar doesn't work, as you are asking a question here. Titles should outline the entirety of a problem so others can solve it a lot easier. Please edit your question for clarity as it will help others answer your question faster. Thanks!

Comment: What does “did not work” mean? What did it do that is different from what you expect?

Comment: Change this `tk.Scrollbar(root` to `tk.Scrollbar(canvas`

Comment: There is no *download* button in your code.  It is better to provide a [mre].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `scrollbars` need to have the `Frame` as a `canvas`, not the    `root`.

This is what you see my example as I so workaround. The `scrollbar` is activated That you can see.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk


root=tk.Tk()

image = tk.PhotoImage(file='p1.png')
def display_image(image):
     
    # convert the image to Tkinter format
     

    # create a canvas with a scrollbar
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
    canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

    scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(canvas, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
    scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

    canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))

    # display the image in the canvas
    canvas_image = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=image)
    canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

    # add a button to save the image
    save_button = tk.Button(canvas, text="Save").pack()
    canvas.create_window(10, 10, anchor="nw", window=save_button)


display_image(image)

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]